# Process explorer's Thread values don't display the total amount for that Process

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, 64-bit, process, process-explorer

I would like process explorer to display on the process details the total amount of the quantity used by all its threads in each field. From the looks of the following picture, a Google Chrome example, this doesn't happen.

[image]

Apparently there is a Google chrome process and various other children threads (indented further), and each has separate values. Take for example the working set field. The process says 300K and all its threads amount to a total of roughly 600k. I would like for the process to display the total quantity used by it (at least when i press the [-] button to collapse the process details}. I hope that was clear. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe Process Explorer has that ability. One problem being that due to memory sharing between processes such a total would often be inaccurate. You would be better off using Chromes built in task manager which has Chrome specific knowledge that Process Explorer does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indented lines do not represent threads, they are completely separate processes (each with one or more threads) created by the process that's above them in the tree display. The numbers you see *are* the totals for each process.

Incidentally, threads don't "use" memory at all. Memory is charged to the process, not to threads.

Comment: I stand corrected. However this doesn't solve my request.

Comment: So, what you really want to do is display the memory used by all processses of a given name? Sometimes the answer is "there is no facility for that".

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do. I think it would be very convenient to find out how many resources are assigned for example to chrome, without going through all its processes and counting. How come they did not add this feature, i wonder.